# set all values from column as variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, cursor

Here is my example and I appreciate for your help!

I created a temp_table with two columns: **agency_id** and **budget**. As a next step, I need to use the agency_id to find out the latest date in which the budget was reported, which varies of course. Therefore, I thought to set the column agency_id as a variable and plug it into the query that generates the data with the latest reporting date.

This is my code which fails:

```
declare @agency int 
set @agency = (select agency_id from ##temp1)
```

However, it gives me this error message:
*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

And this is how I wanted to use it:

```
select max(report_date), @agency from budgets
```

How can I solve this?
Cursor approach?

Thank you so much!

Comment: No you don't want a cursor. They are evil things and should be avoided with very few exceptions. But it is impossible to tell what you are trying to do here. Global temp tables are the spawn of the devil too which is concerning you are using one here. You need to provide details so we can understand what you are doing. Here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: report_date is an integer?  Why would be @agency be in select to assign agency?

Answer (score 1):

Your challenge is that you want to store a list of items, then do a calculation and provide a list of the Items and the maximum date. SQL will optimize that code for you and give you that list much faster.

You need to look at the GROUP BY term in SQL

```
SELECT Agency, MAX(Report_date) FROM Budgets GROUP BY agency
```

I advise you look at the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

or the [w3Schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

This can also be made faster if you index the fields appropriately

Answer (score 1):

```
Try the below instead of Cursors


Create    TABLE   Temp( ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
Agency_id int,
budget int)
DECLARE   @I=1
DECLARE    @COUNT INT
DECLARE   @Agency
SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM temp table
WHILE (@I<=@COUNT)
BEGIN 
SELECT @Agency = Agency FROM temp table WHERE ID = @I
SELECT max(report_date), Agency FROM budgets WHERE Agency = @Agency 
SET @I = @I+1;
END
```